# What is a reason why two PySpark dataframes wouldn't be equal if they have the same schema and data?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose we have two PySpark dataframes `df1` and `df2`. Also suppose that they have the same number of rows (5 rows). If `df1.schema = df2.schema` and `df1.take(5) = df2.take(5)`, why wouldn't `df1 = df2`?

Answer (score 2):

Data handled by Spark are distributed randomly across worker nodes (or executors), they're also unordered and not predictable. Therefore it makes no sense to compare `df1 == df2`. If you truly want to compare them both, and as long as they have the same schema, you can do `df1.subtract(df2).count() == 0` to see if they have exact same data.

Comment: Would doing assert `df1.take(5) == df2.take(5)` also be a valid way of comparison assuming that both dataframes have 5 rows?

Comment: nope, again, Spark dataframe is unordered by default, and data is distributed, so `df1.take(5)` is different from `df2.take(5)` in terms of **objects**, even though their data might be the same

Comment: So why is `df1.take(5) == df2.take(5)` and `df1 != df2`? That dosen't make sense.

Comment: afaik, dataframe doesn't implement `__eq__` which is called when you do `==` comparison. So`df1 == df2` will return true only if the objects are exactly same objects in memory which is unlikely in your case.  While `take` returns `list` of `Row`s which is the extension of `tuple`.  Both `list` & `tuple` implemented element wise equality. Thus, if you got the list of Rows in same order from `df1` and `df2`, *coincidently*, `df1.take(5)` can be equal to `df2.take(5)`.
As @pltc mentioned dataframe is unordered, please note about coincident.